# How to have topic directive show up in table of contents?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx

The topic directive (found here: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#topic) is said to be used as a "self-contained section".

How can I make the title of each topic box show up in the table of contents, like a normal section title would?